# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Christianity's [third moderator election](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Peter Turner] [image: Nathaniel]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

I'd also like to thank [David](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/721/david) who is stepping down. He's been a wonderful addition to the team and I hope he will continue to be a leader on the site for years to come. Please join me in showing your appreciation.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5179045738184704).

Comment: Why does the [summary report](http://www.opavote.org/results/5179045738184704) say the results were counted with Instant Runoff Voting? On OpaVote, that's a different counting option than Meek STV, which is what [the 2013 election](https://www.opavote.com/results/2208002/0) used and which [the current election](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/election/3) indicates was used. I grabbed the .blt file for this election and ran it with Meek STV (though there were other options I didn't understand) using the provided application and the end result is the same, but it gets there differently.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: I forgot to check the correct box. Sorry about that. Fortunately the results are often the same, but I need to always use Meek STV which isn't the default. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. I'm a little concerned that OpaVote allows users to change the counting mechanism without the webpage indicating any changes were made, but since SE is clear and consistent about its counting rules it doesn't really matter in this case. But someone should hound OpaVote for more transparency.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations to you both! Now get to work!

Answer (score 5):

A most warmest congratulations to you both, Peter and Nathaniel. May your tenure as moderators be very fruitful to both of you as well as the whole community here on Christianity SE.

I also wish to thank all those who ran for this position and everyone who participated in voting and more importantly by prayer.

**God Bless each and every one of you!**

Answer (score 4):

### I would like to congratulate Nate and Pete

The following concession speech is provided for closure

*I would like to thank the three people with sufficient sense of humor to vote for me.  I'd like to acknowledge the sharp eyed voting officials who avoided a C.SE zombie apocalypse by catching the dozens of graveyard denizens from Duval and Jim Wells counties who left their eternal rest and tried to stuff the SE ballot box on my behalf.  Well done.  To the rest of the voters, you chose well.*

Comment: I voted for you.

Comment: Thank you very much. :)